# REST API JWT Authentication Header not working in Bitnami Wordpress Instance

Tags: php, wordpress, jwt, bitnami, wordpress-rest-api

Trying to use JWT for Rest APIs deployed on my WordPress(Bitnami - GCP) instance, though the token generates just fine. But on other APIs wherein I pass it in the 'Authorization' Header, it throws an unauthorized error(On localhost works fine). After going through several forums even tried to edit .htaccess through SSH terminal(Permission denied).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]


SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

How to fix this issue on Bitnami WordPress Instance? Thank you

Comment: Ask their support: https://community.bitnami.com/

Comment: @MaksimKuzmin I did ask their support team too. I Will update here too once I get the answer. Thanks

Comment: Any update on this? I am facing this right now :(

Comment: @AndresFelipe Nope I don't use WordPress blog anymore, migrated to gatsby, netlify stack long back